# Client's website is not showing up as expected in Google local searches or maps

Tags: google, search-engines, google-search, google-maps, google-local-search

I'm working for a client who runs a wellness center. He has a website as well as a Google Places account for the business. The Google Places account has a lot of tags associated with it that are relevant to the offerings from the center, and yet it doesn't show up on Google maps or in the local search results for really obvious searches like "massage [name of city]".

I don't have access to the Google Places account yet, but I'm wondering if there's any way to check to see if there's some obvious problem with how things are set up. I can include the link to the website/Google Places pages. I didn't want to do that right away in case it wasn't allowed.

Thanks in advance for any help!

It doesn't seem to me like this question is a duplicate of the one indicated. In this case there **is** a Google Places account, but it's not showing up in the local search results or anywhere on the map for anything other than the name of the wellness center itself. If this Google Place account isn't working properly, would it be advisable to create a new one for the same location, re-verify with google, mark the old one for deletion and then hope the new one works better? Are there any obvious configuration issues I should look for that might explain why this center doesn't even show up on the map for a search of "[name of first listed category] [name of city]"? I have worked with Google Places before and never encountered this type of problem.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't do website reviews which leaves us to speculation only. But having a Google places account is huge for local search so without that it shouldn't be *too* surprising that this site doesn't do well in Google local or maps search.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I specified that there is in fact a Google Places account for the business and as far as I can tell it's set up properly. If it isn't working as expected, would it be an okay strategy to create a new google places account, re-verify, and then mark the old one as a duplicate and hope it works better the second time around?